# React propTypes outside Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I was into functional Javascript previously, Recently I started with Object oriented Javascript and React Library. This question is more of understanding the code.

Why below code don't work

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component{

    propTypes : {
      name: React.PropTypes.string.isReequired,
      location: React.PropTypes.string
    }

    render(){
      return(
        <h1>Hello This is {this.props.name} and I live in 
        {this.props.location}</h1>
      );
    }
  }

  ReactDOM.render(
    <MyComponent name="Node" location="DOM"/>,
    document.getElementById('root')
  );
```

Whereas this code works,

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component{
    render(){
      return(
        <h1>Hello This is {this.props.name} and I live in {this.props.location}</h1>
      );
    }
  }

  MyComponent.propTypes = {
    name: React.PropTypes.string.isReequired,
    location: React.PropTypes.string
  }

  ReactDOM.render(
    <MyComponent name="Node" location="DOM"/>,
    document.getElementById('root')
  );
```

Can someone help me understand this? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `static` word (to define the static property) because, `propTypes` need to be declared on the `class` itself, not on the instance of the `class` , and use `=`.

Check the [DOC](https://babeljs.io/blog/2015/06/07/react-on-es6-plus).

Like this:

```
static propTypes = {
    name: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    location: React.PropTypes.string
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This makes sense :)

Answer (score 2):

Inside an ES6 class, static properties look like this

```
class X extends Y {
    static staticThing = {
        ...    
    }
}
```

note the `=`

"assigning" a static property the ES5 way looks like the second way you have it there

Typically, you'll use the second way for functional components whereas you might as well use the first way (albeit properly with an `=`) for ES6 style class components.

also, make sure you have your `React.PropTypes` correct - `isReequired` should be `isRequired`

Comment: Thank you. Now i understood.